# Simple hex value convert to Enum type value problem

Tags: c#, enums

I have been fighting with this little problem for a night and I couldn't figure it out.  All I want is have some enum elements with Hex value and convert a value to enum, but .NET somehow don't think my enum is legal.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class CommandEnum
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum Command : byte
        {
            CMD_HAND_SHAKE = 0x0,
            CMD_SET_MAX_CURRENT = 0x1,
            CMD_SET_TEST_SPEED = 0xA
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CommandEnum command;
            byte receiveByte = 0x0A;

            // Error: Type provided must be an Enum. Parameter name: enumType:
            command = (CommandEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(CommandEnum), receiveByte);  
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong and how should I fix it?

Comment: This is probably very stupid question, as I am not too familiar with C#, but aren't Enumerations comparable to integers (== hex values)?

Comment: @inestical yes they are. You can cast to / from enums to integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
command = (CommandEnum.Command)receiveByte;
```

and `command` should be defined as

```
ConnamdEnum.Command command
```

Generally, it looks like you do not need a wrapper class `CommandEnum`, you should just define `enum Command`

Answer (score 1):

`CommandEnum` is not an enum, it is a class! You have defined your enum `Command` as an 'inner' enum, so the following should work:

```
command = (CommandEnum.Command)Enum.ToObject(typeof(CommandEnum.Command),
                                             receiveByte);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing it the name of the class containing your enum `CommandEnum`, instead of the name of your enum, `CommandEnum.Command`.  The following should work for you:

```
CommandEnum.Command command = (CommandEnum.Command)Enum.ToObject(typeof(CommandEnum.Command), receiveByte);
```

Also, the syntax that you are using is fairly convoluted, you can just cast instead:

```
CommandEnum.Command command1 = (CommandEnum.Command)receiveByte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CommandEnum.Command command;
byte receiveByte = 0x0A;

// Error: Type provided must be an Enum. Parameter name: enumType:
command = (CommandEnum.Command)Enum.ToObject(typeof(CommandEnum.Command), receiveByte);
```

or better,

```
command = (CommandEnum.Command)receiveByte;
```

In your original code you are using all the wrong types. Your enumeration type is a public nested type for `CommandEnum` class (and there is really no good reason to do something like that). Try to get rid of `CommandEnum` class and justuse the `Command` enum.

Answer (score 0):

Since your enum is typeof(byte) just cast it, no need to do anything else

`CommandEnum.Command val= (CommandEnum.Command)receiveByte;`

P.S. You can't have a 0x00 flag.